# alarm app not working shows error in pendingintent

Tags: java, android

here code for alarm

**AlarmManagerExample.java**

```
package com.example.alarmmanagerexample;

import java.util.Calendar;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmManagerExample extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_manager_example);


        try {
             Button  btnSet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
                final   DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.scheduleTimePicker);
                final   TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

                btnSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
                            int month = dp.getMonth();
                            int year = dp.getYear();
                            int currentTime =tp.getCurrentHour();
                            int currentMinute=tp.getCurrentMinute();
                        //  int hour =timePicker.getti
                            // Create a new calendar set to the date chosen
                            // we set the time to midnight (i.e. the first minute of that day)
                            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                            c.set(year, month, day);
                            c.set(currentTime, currentMinute);
                        String strDateTime = dp.getYear() + "-" + (dp.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dp.getDayOfMonth() + " "+ tp.getCurrentHour() + ":" + tp.getCurrentMinute();


            //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmManagerExample.this, RingAlarm.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmManagerExample.this,c, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am =
                (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                    2*60*60,pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(AlarmManagerExample.this, "User has selected " + strDateTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();// move to previous activity
                    }});

          } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

above code am getting error in pendingintent line error

**RingAlarm.java**

```
package com.example.alarmmanagerexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class RingAlarm extends Activity {

       MediaPlayer mp=null ;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                    setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
                    Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.audio);


                    stopAlarm.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mp.stop();
                            finish();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    playSound(this, getAlarmUri());
                }

                private void playSound(final Context context, Uri alert) {


                    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                               mp.start();

                            } catch (Throwable t) {
                                Log.i("Animation", "Thread  exception "+t);
                            }   
                        }
                 });
                 background.start();
               }

                @Override
                protected void onDestroy() {
                    super.onDestroy();
                    mp.stop();
                }               //Get an alarm sound. Try for an alarm. If none set, try notification,
                    //Otherwise, ringtone.
                private Uri getAlarmUri() {

                    Uri alert = RingtoneManager
                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                    if (alert == null) {
                        alert = RingtoneManager
                                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        if (alert == null) {
                            alert = RingtoneManager
                                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                        }
                    }
                    return alert;
                }

}
```

Bellow given data are layout pages

**activity_alarm_manager_example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notificatin Create" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/scheduleTimePicker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onDateSelectedButtonClick"
        android:text="Set notification for this date" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**alarm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Stop Alarm" android:id="@+id/stopAlarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmmanagerexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.alarmmanagerexample.AlarmManagerExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RingAlarm"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

how to solve this issue ??

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmManagerExample.this,c, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); here am getting error

Comment: I know, but what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the compiler is complaining about this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmManagerExample.this,c, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

because the second argument, `c` needs to be an `int` value. It looks like you aren't passing an `int` value here. This is the `requestCode` parameter.